# Resize isotope items depending on window size

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-isotope

I'm a newbie and I am searching for a solution to have a media query being rendered in javascript. I need this to alter the height of isotope items according to the window size. I checked the existing topics but I couldn't find an exact answer to this. My script is working except from the media query.

How to apply the **if (screen.width <= 550)**?

```
jQuery(function() {
var jQuerycontainer = jQuery('#isotope-container');
jQuerycontainer.addClass('clickable');

if (screen.width <= 550) {
    jQuerycontainer.isotope({
        animationEngine : "best-available",
        itemSelector : '.isotope-element',
        layoutMode : "perfectMasonry",
        perfectMasonry : {
            columnWidth : 52,
            rowHeight : 15,
        }
    });
} else if (screen.width > 550) {
    jQuerycontainer.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.isotope-element',
        layoutMode : "perfectMasonry",
        perfectMasonry : {
            columnWidth : 52,
            rowHeight : 110,
        }
    });
}

jQuerycontainer.isotope('reload')    etc. etc.
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from the isotope page
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried to implement it, but my isotope container crashes. What  I did:

`jQuery(function() {
 var jQuerycontainer = jQuery('#isotope-container');
 jQuerycontainer.addClass('clickable');

 jQuerycontainer.isotope({
  resizable : false,
  animationEngine : "best-available",
  itemSelector : '.isotope-element',
  layoutMode : "perfectMasonry",
  perfectMasonry : {
   columnWidth : 52
   }
 });
`

Comment: Followed up by

`$(window).smartresize(function() {
  jQuerycontainer.isotope({

  if(screen.width <= 550) { perfectMasonry: { rowHeight :15
   }
  }

  else
  if (screen.width > 550) { perfectMasonry : { rowHeight :110
   }
  }

 });
});

jQuerycontainer.isotope('reload')`